# Finding heteroscedasticity in time series

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, regression

I'm working in python stack (scipy/numpy/pandas) and I need to do a linear fit on a list of (x,y) points that have added noise from some distribution conditioned on x and other global properties. *Are any specific methods available to measure and visualize the levels of heteroscedasticity in my data?*

Comment: You can ask for some statistics help at Cross Validated too! Here's the link: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In fact, that may be the better place to ask. This question is out of scope for SO.

Comment: I asked a few questions there before, never got any responses. @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the tests listed on the [Wikipedia page for Heteroscedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity#Detection) can be found in the [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) package. Under the circumstances, the [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/index.html) package (which is built on top of scipy) may be a better bet. There is an entire module dedicated to [Heteroscedasticity tests](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/diagnostic.html?highlight=heteroscedasticity).

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out that package, what about fitting a distribution on the residuals, I'm new to these libraries, is there an optimal tool?

Comment: Probably scipy.optimize? Also, I am sure that there is some scikit that does what you want (statsmodels is a scikit).